# Start standalone server in JBoss 7.1.1 with Maven 2

Tags: maven, jboss

What kind of configuration has to be done to start JBoss 7.1.1 standalone server or domain server using Maven 2?

- Start
- Stop
- Deploy

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: You can look at [cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin)

Answer (score 0):

See [JBoss Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of issues lately when I tried to deploy a new maven2 java project from eclipse to a fresh copy of jboss as 7.1.1.

After I spent 4 hours reading various online documentation I have finally realised that there are 2 jboss maven plugins; named , jboss maven plugin and jboss as maven plugin.

The first one is located [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/) and the second one [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/).

So, pay attention if you need to use the "jboss-as" goal specifier or the "jboss" goal specifier.

Funny. I am just starting to read in order to see what is the real difference between these two libraries; apart from the obvious goal specifier and the task names.